# Is there a difference in drift and diffusion under forward biasing in a pn junction?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

The current in forward bias is claimed to be because of the diffusion process. 
However, from what I understand, the diffusion process is being supported by the battery by inducing fields in the direction of diffusion current itself. Thus the current we are seeing should be an imposition of drift on diffusion.

Comment: Diffusion current is the random walk of charges, and is always present. Drift diffusion is the (additional) charge movement in response to a field. Total current is always the combination of the two.

Answer (score 1):

*Drift* is a current due to the potential difference, whereas *diffusion* is due to the difference in concentration. Mathematically:
$$
\mathbf{j}_{drift}\propto\nabla\varphi,\\
\mathbf{j}_{diff}\propto\nabla n
$$
In semiconductors both are often present, see, e.g., the last equations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_current#Derivation).

Answer (score 0):

In general, you have always a combination of drift and diffusion current in the pn-junction giving the total current in the 1-dimensional case. In the simple Shockley model for the current of the pn-junction the total current is derived only from the diffusion currents of minority carriers in the semiconductor adjacent to the depletion zone, where the electric field is assumed to be negligible. This is a good approximation due to the quasi-neutrality condition for low minority carrier injection.

Comment: In the simple pn-junction model, the total current is calculated only by the sum of minority carrier (electron and hole) diffusion currents at the edges of the quasi-neutral regions adjacent to the depletion zone. Drift currents are assumed to be negligible there.  This sum of diffusion currents at the edges represents the total current through the 1-dimensional pn-junction due to the neglect of recombination in the depletion zone and total current continuity along the device. At different cross sections, however  this current can be a combination of drift and diffusion or only drift current.